# How to print string and list on same row without square brackets

Tags: python

```
l = [1, 2]
print "My numbers are:", l
```

This gives me

```
My numbers are: [1, 2]
```

but I want

```
My numbers are: 1, 2
```

I have seen `','.join(l)` but I don't know how to print out everything on the same line.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the `join` approach?

Comment: In my program l = [1, 2] not ['1', '2']. Sorry

Comment: @JonathonHill give a [mcve] with the full error traceback, not just a vague description.

Answer (score 2):

For `.join` to work you will have to change every element to `str`:

`print ', '.join(map(str, l))`

Answer (score 0):

Here I used a generator to generate a list of the string values and then I joined them together! I hope this helps!

```
l = [1, 2]
print 'My numbers are: {}'.format(' and '.join(str(x) for x in l))
```

Comment: The OP gave the format he wants, and he does not want "and" between the numbers.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I think he is smart enough to change `'and'` to `', '`... Just because it would be very difficult for you doesn't mean it would be for him!

Comment: I am a newbie to Python, but not to programming. I meant that your answer would be better if you changed your string ' and ' to ', ' to directly answer the OP's question. No offense was intended, just a suggestion for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "My numbers are:", str(l).strip("[]")
```

Use strip. Convert the list in string and then remove the char that you want specifying them in the strip function.